# Error converting nvarchar into int... being a number? - Laravel, SQL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am creating a json to save 2 values of a form that have the same name (`data`) in order to when 2 rows are saved in the table instead of just one at the same time.

**This structure is created like this and cannot be edited.**

In principle it works, but in the end it gives me an error that I am not very convinced that it is a Laravel problem or is just SQL, so I do not know where to go.

I have tried to save the value "1" twice to see what it came out, and the following error has come out:

> SQLSTATE[22018]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion error when converting the value nvarchar '["1","1"]' to data type int. (SQL: insert into [table_data] ([data]) values (["1","1"]))

The DB and the project itself cannot be simpler, so I don't know where to go, any idea?.

##### DB Structure

> - ID (INT, Primary Key, AUTOINCREMENT)
> - Data (INT)

##### `DataController.php`

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\data;

use App\Data;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests\StoreDataPost;

class DataController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('data', ['Data' => new Data()]);
    }

    public function store(StoreDataPost $request)
    {
        $json = json_encode($request->get('data')); 
        Data::create(['data' => $json]);
    }
}
```

##### `Data.php`

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Data extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'table_data';

    protected $primaryKey = 'ID';

    protected $fillable = [
        'data'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function getDataAttribute()
    {
       return json_decode($this->data);
    }
}
```

##### `StoreDataPost.php`

```php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreDataPost extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'data.*' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

##### `data.blade.php`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Send Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{{ route("store") }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        
        {{-- Data in field 1 in DB --}
        <div>
            <input type="number" name="data[]" id="data">
        </div>

        {{-- Data in field 2 in DB --}
        <div>
            <input type="number" name="data[]" id="data">
        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it's trying to insert array inside an integer column, Try this instead the code in your store method:

```
public function store(StoreDataPost $request)
{
    foreach (request('data') as $val) {
        Data::create(['data' => $val]);
    }
}
```

Comment: OH MY GOD IT WORKED!!! Thanks pal!!! Quick question, what happen if I add 2 more field repeated? For example "data_string" x2 (Strings in DB)? What are the changes I must do here and in the other codes?

Comment: Do you mean add more than tow inputs ?

Comment: That's correct. For example, in the blade, add 2 more inputs called `data_string` (same case as `data` in the DB) and when I submit them I must save the 2 previous `data` x2 (int) and the new `data_string` x2 (string) sharing the same row in the DB. Do I explain right or you wanna I wrote the blade in a new answer?

Comment: Whatever the length of ```request('data')``` will be the result of the same length in the database

Comment: But how it be the correct syntax? `foreach (request('data', 'data_string') as $val) { Data::create(['data' => $val, 'data_string' => $val]);` ??